# A .gtf file for HG38 for HISAT2 indexing

Tags: python, gtf, human-genome

I am trying to build a HISAT2 index using Pertea et al. procedure (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27560171) using their `extract_splice_sites.py` and `extract_exons.py` pieces of code. For that, I need a `.gtf` file of Human Genome HG38. I have obtained this file using recommendations described here http://www.metagenomics.wiki/tools/fastq/ncbi-ftp-genome-download

The file I have downloaded is `GCF_000001405.39_GRCh38.p13_genomic.gff` (1,1 Gb) and when I use on it this command `python3 extract_splice_sites.py GCF_000001405.39_GRCh38.p13_genomic.gff > test.ss` my `test.ss` file is 0 Kb! I wonder if there's another `.gff` file that I must use and where I can get it? This is my first time working with the human genome so I am not sure if I am doing the procedure the right way.

Comment: you might wanna try python2.7 https://www.biostars.org/p/293881/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download a GTF file from NCBI now. For hg38 (also known as GRCh38), just go to [NCBI Assembly](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/assembly) and search for 'GRCh38'. Click on the first result to go to [this page](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/assembly/GCF_000001405.39) and use the blue 'Download Assemblies' button to download data. Here, after you choose 'RefSeq' as your source of data, you will see a GTF file to download from the drop-down list, as shown in the screenshot below: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I was able to solve it with that
https://github.com/NBISweden/GAAS/blob/master/annotation/knowledge/gff_to_gtf.md